# How to subset a list of data frames using a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr

I have just started to work with lists in R and I have a problem that I can't seem to be able to solve, since I don't know how to subset or filter lists.
I have a list with 9 data frames

```
List of 9
 $ :'data.frame':   41999 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:41999] "193.722:175.733" "192.895:176.727" "187.065:178.285" "190.754:178.186" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41999] 0 0 7 0 0 7 8 8 7 8 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   42069 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:42069] "192.895:176.727" "187.065:178.285" "190.754:178.186" "192.296:178.648" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:42069] 0 7 7 0 8 7 8 8 7 8 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   42116 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:42116] "192.296:178.648" "178.899:180.92" "182.416:181.265" "186.806:181.434" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:42116] 0 8 8 7 7 8 7 8 7 7 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   41976 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:41976] "193.722:175.733" "190.654:176.113" "188.362:176.407" "192.895:176.727" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41976] 0 7 7 0 7 7 7 7 8 7 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   41949 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:41949] "190.654:176.113" "188.362:176.407" "192.895:176.727" "186.064:177.413" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41949] 0 0 0 7 7 0 0 7 7 8 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   42020 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:42020] "190.754:178.186" "192.296:178.648" "189.421:179.012" "186.453:179.2" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:42020] 0 0 0 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   41902 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:41902] "191.802:173.732" "193.722:175.733" "183.882:176.123" "190.654:176.113" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41902] 0 0 7 0 0 0 8 7 7 0 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   42072 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:42072] "190.754:178.186" "192.296:178.648" "189.421:179.012" "178.899:180.92" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:42072] 0 0 0 8 7 8 7 7 8 7 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   41956 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : chr [1:41956] "193.722:175.733" "190.654:176.113" "188.362:176.407" "192.895:176.727" ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41956] 0 0 7 0 8 7 7 7 7 8 ...
```

Where the first column is XY_ID and the second is called CellID.
I also have a vector with the YX_IDs that are common to all 9 data frames (column 1). I extracted these common XY_ID like this:

```
csv4 <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(csv3, function(x){
    x[['XY_ID']]
}))

str(csv4)
 chr [1:35368] "192.296:178.648" "182.416:181.265" "186.806:181.434" "188.737:181.429" ...
```

Now what I want to do is for each XY_ID in csv4 (vector) find the match in columns 1 (XY_ID) of each datafarme in csv3 and print the CellID that goes with it.

The output should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the `list`, `subset` the dataset, and `rbind` the datasets with `do.call`

```
out1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(csv3, function(x) subset(x, XY_ID %in% csv4)))
```

---

Or another option is `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out2 <- map_dfr(csv3, ~ .x  %>%
                          filter(XY_ID %in% csv4))
```